# Fill in a google document with values in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a google apps script that does the following:

1. First add a custom menu into google sheet with all the values of column C
2. When the user presses on a certain value a function runs and does the following:
   2.1. Create a copy of a google document
   2.2. Fill in the placeholders according to the columns headers (for example the second column called "Project", so if the script finds {{Project}} it fills it in with the value in the row that the user selected from the custom menu.
   2.3. Put the new document in a destination folder.

can someone help me please???

thanks.

I didn't try anything. I am stuck.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `First add a custom menu into google sheet with all the values of column C` and `When the user presses on a certain value`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your current script? And, can I ask you about the details of your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Instead of adding a custom menu to the menu bar, I would recommend you use a dropdown in a cell coupled with the `onEdit()` trigger.

Answer (score 0):

**Fill in a google doc with google sheets using google apps script**

GS:

```
function one() {
  const df = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.folder1id);dest folder id
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//Sheet name
  const row = sh.getActiveCell().getRow();//row selected
  const dsr = 2;//data start row
  const [hs, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const arr = vs.map(r => hs.reduce((a, h, i) => (a[h] = r[i], a.pA = [...a.pA,h], a), {pA:[]}));returns an array of objects
  if (row > 1 && row < dsr + arr.length ) {
    let id = arr[row - dsr]["TemplateId"];
    let t = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    let rep = arr[row - dsr]["Replacements"];
    let f = t.makeCopy(`${t.getName()}-${Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"ddMMYYhhmmss")}`,df);
    let doc = DocumentApp.openById(f.getId());
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let narr = arr[row - dsr].pA.slice(0, rep);
    narr.forEach((h,i) => body.replaceText(`{{${h}}}`,arr[row - dsr][h]));
    doc.saveAndClose();
  }
}
```

The way I organized my data in Sheet0:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | TemplateId | Replacements |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 32 | 19 | 9 | 0 | 3 | 33 | 14 | Redacted | 8 |
| 4 | 30 | 1 | 6 | 27 | 8 | 8 | 25 | Redacted | 8 |
| 28 | 26 | 32 | 21 | 24 | 31 | 30 | 17 | Redacted | 8 |
| 34 | 16 | 30 | 11 | 11 | 28 | 6 | 2 | Redacted | 8 |
| 34 | 0 | 8 | 3 | 27 | 26 | 12 | 23 | Redacted | 8 |
| 29 | 9 | 14 | 27 | 15 | 19 | 10 | 9 | Redacted | 8 |
| 0 | 4 | 12 | 18 | 13 | 25 | 0 | 28 | Redacted | 8 |
| 28 | 14 | 15 | 15 | 3 | 27 | 7 | 5 | Redacted | 8 |
| 17 | 17 | 9 | 29 | 20 | 5 | 9 | 9 | Redacted | 8 |

testdoc before:

[image]

testdoc after with row 2 selected:

[image]

- [Array.methods()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

> I would not have known how to write this in this way without the ability to read and learn from the answers of other volunteers so thank you Tanaike, TheMaster, TheWizEd and yes even doubleunary.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out myself. I appreciate your effort.